# Is there any possible way to close android snackbar (LENGTH_INDEFINITE)automatically while internet connected without any action?

Tags: android, android-snackbar, snackbar

I have displayed android snack bar with **INDEFINITE LENGTH** but how to close snack bar with out any action or duration while Internet connected . I have to check internet connected or not.after internet connected snack bar will be closed  automatically without any action or duration.If anybody knows kindly help me.

here is my code

```
public static void snack (HashMap<String,View.OnClickListener> actions,int priority,String message,Activity context){
    Snackbar B = Snackbar.make(context.findViewById(android.R.id.content), message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
    if(actions!=null){
    Iterator iterator = actions.entrySet().iterator();
        B.setDuration(Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
        B.setAction((String)pair.getKey(),(View.OnClickListener)pair.getValue());
        iterator.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
    }}
    switch (priority)
    {
        case 0:
            B.getView().setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_pinkbutton));
            break;
        case 1:
            B.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#66ccff"));
            break;
        case 2:
            B.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#66ff33"));
            break;
    }
    B.show();
```

after calling above mentioned method using  the activity is as follows

```
If (NetworkCheck.isNetworkAvailable(this) == false) {
    MyApplication.snack(null, 0, "Network Connection failed.",class.this);
else
```

Answer (score 10):

I have made this singleton utility class.
It kept the application class cleaner and best for future maintainability of snack bars.

```
public class SnackBarUtils {
    private static SnackBarUtils mInstance = null;
    private Snackbar mSnackBar;

    private SnackBarUtils() {

    }

    public static SnackBarUtils getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new SnackBarUtils();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public void hideSnackBar() {
        if (mSnackBar != null) {
            mSnackBar.dismiss();
        }
    }

    public void showProblemSnackBar(final Activity activity, final String message) {
        mSnackBar = Snackbar.make(activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content), message, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
        // Changing action button text color
        View sbView = mSnackBar.getView();
        TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
        mSnackBar.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't close the `snackbar` when I call the method `hideSnackBar()`.

Comment: FYI, you should include the use cases for clarity: `SnackBarUtils.getInstance().showProblemSnackBar(activity, msg)` and `SnackBarUtils.getInstance().hideSnackBar()`

Answer (score 1):

You can make changes in you code as follows:

```
   Snackbar B; //make it as global

    public static void snack (HashMap<String,View.OnClickListener> actions,int priority,String message,Activity context){
      B = Snackbar.make(context.findViewById(android.R.id.content), message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
      if(actions!=null){
      Iterator iterator = actions.entrySet().iterator();
        B.setDuration(Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
      while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
        B.setAction((String)pair.getKey(),(View.OnClickListener)pair.getValue());
        iterator.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
      }}
      switch (priority){
        case 0:
                B.getView().setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_pinkbutton));
            break;
        case 1:
            B.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#66ccff"));
            break;
        case 2:
            B.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#66ff33"));
            break;
    }
    B.show();
```

Make another method for hiding snackbar as

```
private static hideSnackbar(){
   if(B !=null && B.isShown()){
           B.dismiss();
   }
}
```

And in your condition

```
If (NetworkCheck.isNetworkAvailable(this) == false) {
    MyApplication.snack(null, 0, "Network Connection failed.",class.this)
}else{
    MyApplication.hideSnackbar();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but In the same activity internet disconnected snack bar displayed . after Internet connected in the same page snack bar not closed

Comment: can you show me the code how you doing it??? edit your question and paste the code there

Comment: I have implemented as per your code.the problem is when  same activity I have disconnected the network snack bar not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You should just create broadcast receiver and receive the following event
`<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>` and subscribe on it in your activity/fragment

Full info is here http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html

Comment: Thanks .I will implement as per your scenario

Comment: broadcase receiver I have Implemented but not worked.I have mentioned the code above.

Answer (score 0):

For kotlin folks, add this method to your Utils class

```
fun showNoNetworkSnackBar(activity: Activity,message: String):Snackbar {
        val snackbar: Snackbar = Snackbar.make(
            activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content),
            message, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE
        )

        return snackbar
    }
```

Then call it like this

```
   val snackbar = Utils.showNoNetworkSnackBar(this,"No Internet")
   snackbar.show or snackbar.dismiss
```